# Inserting into two different database tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form that will insert users input from a form into database, I want to store the email in a separate table to the users.

So I want the email in an accounts table and then the username and password in a users table. For anyone wondering why, the application I want to build will allow users to create a new user after dying but can have stuff stored in the accounts that will be carried over.

I tried working with multiple of the same code but just gets too much and get lost in it all. There must be an easier way to do than multiple copied of stretched code.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../register.php?error=Sql_Error");
        exit();
        
    } else {
        
    
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $character);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
        
     if ($resultCheck > 0) {
         header("Location: ../register.php?error=CharacterTaken&email=".$emailAddress); 
         exit();
     } else {
         
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=Sql_Error");
            exit;
            
            
        } else {
            
        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $character, $emailAddress, $hashedPwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../register.php?success=Account Created.");
```

Comment: I didn't get it ? Can you be more clear?

Comment: I have 2 tables in mysql database, one called accounts which I wish the email to be stored and another called users which I wish the user_name and password to be stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to insert separate data in separate tables I suggest you just to use 2 separate INSERT queries.

As there is one part of your code doing it already, the easiest way is to adjust it and duplicate it:

Replace this part of code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_email, user_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=Sql_Error");
            exit;


        } else {

        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $character, $emailAddress, $hashedPwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

With this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=Sql_Error");
            exit;
        } else {

        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $character, $hashedPwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (user_email) VALUES (?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=Sql_Error");
            exit;
        } else {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $emailAddress);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: yeah that's what I tried to do adjust and duplicate but was driving me crazy, will give it a go thanks.

Comment: Hope it works. Let me know, accepting answer would be appriciated :)

Comment: got it to work thank you very very much. :) Think I selected it as an answer.